# Daemon is performed only once

Tags: c, linux, daemon

I want to write a daemon which will write the contents of the folder every 5 seconds. Unfortunately, this is done only once. What to do to be done cyclically? I dont have any idea how to do.

```
struct dirent *file;
struct stat file_details;
while (1)
{    
    while((file=readdir(source))!=NULL)
    {
        if(file->d_type!=DT_REG) continue;
        fprintf(stderr,"Name: %s \n",file->d_name);
    }

    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Try openning (opendir (source)) and closing the dir (closedir(source)) every time.

Comment: * source=opendir () and closedir(source)  every time.